# How to get id Oracle PHP RETURNING INTO

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Oracle 12c + PHP

How to get id from this query:

```
$execute = "INSERT INTO DODATEK SELECT NVL(MAX(dodatekid),0)+1,'$randomString' from DODATEK";
```

What i have tried with 
oci_bind_by_name and RETURNING INTO

```
$c = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$executeforId = "INSERT INTO DODATEK SELECT NVL(MAX(dodatekid),0)+1,'$randomString' from DODATEK RETURNING dodatekid INTO :dodatekId";
$exForId = oci_parse($c,$executeforId);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':dodatekId', $dodatekIdForTxt);
echo $dodatekIdForTxt;
```

And i got Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Use `$exForId` instead of `$stid`

Comment: warning is gone but returning is not working

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> You must specify **maxlength** when using an *OUT* bind so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.

So try adding maxlength and type parameters in the bind:

```
`oci_bind_by_name($exForId, ':dodatekId', $dodatekIdForTxt, -1, OCI_B_INT);`
```

Comment: I added that and everytime i get 0 in response